# Selenium Webdriver- clicking on invisible link, which is display when we move mouse over it

Tags: selenium

when we mouse over a link then it is visible, which command is use to click on this link.How to click on this link.we use Actions builder command but it is not working.

Comment: can you provide the html code?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = localDriver.findElement(By.Xpath(""));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.build();
actions.perform();
```